# Using RestTemplate to call a WebFlux microservice

Tags: spring-mvc, resttemplate, spring-webflux

Is it possible to call a Spring WebFlux API from a Spring MVC App using RestTemplate?

I get a 200 response however the body is null, this isn't an object mapping issue because I am just trying to return a string at this point. If I make the same request against the WebFlux API in a browser or Postman the body is as expected.

Is there a way to get RestTemplate to work? I don't want to have to update all of my apps to WebFlux right now.

Comment: if your app is returning a Mono then yes, if it is returning a Flux, then no.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is using HTTP protocol, you can definitely use RestTemplate or even any other HttpClient from whatever language you want to communicate with WebFlux REST API.

If request is working from postman then you can try debugging your code around RestTemplate to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You are right! If you inspect the response headers, content-size when calling with a restTemplate is 0! And if you debug restTemplate you will notice in the extractor when content size is 0, it will return null for body.
I couldn't find a way around it and it seems that the only solution is using WebClient. Anyway RestTemplate is gonna deprecate soon but I agree it's so annoying that your service client should be aware not to use RestTemplate when you return `Mono<Void>`.

Here is the code inside the `MessageBodyClientHttpResponseWrapper implements ClientHttpResponse` class that returns false if the content-length is 0:

```
public boolean hasMessageBody() throws IOException {
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.resolve(getRawStatusCode());
    if (status != null && (status.is1xxInformational() || status == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT ||
            status == HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getHeaders().getContentLength() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```